# How to return composite JSON objects in Laravel?

Tags: json, api, laravel

I was reading the Laravel documentation and unfortunately it didn't tell me how to make composite JSON objects.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization

So right now I have two entities: User and Post and I want to return a JSON object containing the User as the parent (JSON) and Posts as the children of User (JSON) in the JSON object. There is a one-to-many relationship between User and Post.

Here is the controller method I want to change:

```
public function show($user)
{
    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fetch the the relationship when querying a user:

```
$user = User::find(123)->with('posts')->get();
```

Then return a JSON response.

```
return response()->json($user);
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rubens Mariuzzo answer, if you haven't done this, you first need to declare relationship in your model

```
# User Model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Post');
}
```

Then you will be able to do as Rubens Mariuzzo stated

`$user = User::find(123)->with('posts')->get();`